# xcode: how to debug in xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have a Person class which has only a property: name. I want to list the property value when debug, but xcode just display "isa", how can I do it like in eclipse?

Xcode :
[image]

eclipse:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the hood, properties are accessed using methods.  A property named `name` can be read using the `name` method, and it can be set using the `setName:` method.  You can use the debugger's `po` command to print a description of an object.  Try typing this at the debugger console:

```
po [p name]
```

The `po` command works by sending the `debugDescription` message to the object you're printing, and by default, `debugDescription` just sends the `description` message.  So you could add this method to your `Person` class:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<%@: %p name=%@>", self.class, self, self.name];
}
```

Then you can use a debugger command like this:

```
po p
```

and get output like this:

```
<Person: 0x10013fd60 name=Jack>
```

Comment: thank you, so you mean I can't just list all properties in debug area? Or is there any way to do that? maybe using instance variable instead of property?

Comment: Not being able to see all instance variables is a problem in the current version of Xcode.  You might have better luck by switching to the LLDB debugger (in your scheme settings), or you might just have to wait for a future version of Xcode and hope it's fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If rob's post did not work, then i would try typing in bt (for backtrace) in the console